# How to Kill a script in Visual Studio Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I would like to stop the script from continuing, how do I do this?

I've tried using `break;` and `Response.End;` and neither seem to work.

The application is in VS 2013 Pro as a Console application.

Comment: What script are you trying to stop from continuing?

Comment: I'm not sure what script you're trying to run, but have you tried `return;`?

Comment: Response.End in console app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply return from the `Program.Main()` method like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        if (condition)
            return; //this will exit the program


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Console.Readline();` to wait for user input.

Edit:

However, if you're just trying to debug your application you can set a breakpoint down with `F9`.

Comment: Did'nt think of that and it should workout for me, but there is nothing specifically to kill a script is there?

Comment: It might be easier for us to help you if you tell us what it is you are *trying* to do rather than what it is you *want* to do.